# Define Map in Java

Tags: java, android

Below code defined in JavaScript, it stores keys and array of values, how can I defined it in Java

```
charList: {
      "0000": ['a', 'p', 'G', 'W', 'é'],
      "0001": ['b', 'r', 'H', 'X', '!'],
      "0010": ['c', 's', 'I', 'Y', '+'],
      "0011": ['d', 't', 'J', 'Z', '$'],
      "0100": ['e', 'u', 'K', '1', '%'],
      "0101": ['f', 'v', 'L', '2', '&'],
      "0110": ['g', 'w', 'M', '3', '('],
      "0111": ['h', 'x', 'N', '4', ')'],
      "1000": ['i', 'y', 'O', '5', '?'],
      "1001": ['j', 'z', 'P', '6', '_'],
      "1010": ['k', 'A', 'Q', '7', '€'],
      "1011": ['l', 'B', 'R', '8', '@'],
      "1100": ['m', 'C', 'S', '9', '€'],
      "1101": ['n', 'D', 'T', '0', '#'],
      "1110": ['o', 'E', 'U', '*', '{'],
      "1111": ['q', 'F', 'V', '-', '}'],
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in two ways please refer to the below example.

```
        // Method1
        Map<String, Character[]> map1 = new HashMap<String, Character[]>();

        map1.put("0000", new Character[] { 'a', 'p', 'G', 'W', 'é' });
        map1.put("0001", new Character[] { 'b', 'r', 'H', 'X', '!' });
        map1.put("0010", new Character[] { 'c', 's', 'I', 'Y', '+' });



        // Method2
        Map<String, List<Character>> map2 = new HashMap<>();

        map2.put("0000", Arrays.asList('a', 'p', 'G', 'W', 'é'));
        map2.put("0001", Arrays.asList('b', 'r', 'H', 'X', '!'));
        map2.put("0010", Arrays.asList('c', 's', 'I', 'Y', '+'));

        System.out.println(map2.get("0000")); //OP: [a, p, G, W, é] //List
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below,

```
Map<String , Character[]> x = new HashMap<String, Character[]>();
```

OR

```
Map<String , List<String> x = new HashMap<String, List<String>();
```

If you use String List, you will have more control over list than Character Array.

Comment: For the second one instead of List<String> better to use List<Character>.